# ProxyPass not redirecting to the specified port in Virtualhost

Tags: apache, port, virtualhost, sap-commerce-cloud, proxypass

I want to access https://localhost:9002/login.jsp  using https://localhost url (without giving the port 9002)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass         / https://localhost:9002/
    ProxyPassReverse  / https://localhost:9002/
</VirtualHost>
```

This is what I have given in 000-default.conf , Can someone please help me to correct this, I have gone through multiple solutions, but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please use the below configuration.

..................................................................................

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/example/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/example/
</VirtualHost>
```

After you make these changes, add the needed modules and restart apache

```
sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http && sudo service apache2 restart
```